# Los fragmentos de Android Studio JAVA desaparecen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

Tengo un menú inferior y un tablayout, cuando inicio la aplicación la tabLayout funciona correctamente como se puede ver en la foto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando selecciono un botón de la actividad inferior que tengo a continuación y vuelvo a donde estaba, me pasa que los fragmentos ya no están y no aparece nada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo por qué me pasa esto, este es mi código:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_unete, container, false);


tablayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
viewpager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

//initialize adapter
adapter = new 
MainAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
//add fragment
adapter.AddFragment(new OneUnete(), "Conqueror's Blade");
adapter.AddFragment(new TwoUnete(), "Warframe");

//set adapter
viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
//connect tab layout with view pager
tablayout.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);


return view;
}

private class MainAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
//iniciar array  list
ArrayList<Fragment> fragmentArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

//create constructor
public void AddFragment(Fragment fragment, String s){
    //add fragment
    fragmentArrayList.add(fragment);
    //add string
    stringArrayList.add(s);
}

public MainAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentActivity) {
    super(fragmentActivity);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    //return fragment
    return fragmentArrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    //return fragmentlist size
    return fragmentArrayList.size();
}


@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

    return stringArrayList.get(position);


}
```

aqui el xml de unete

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".UneteFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabBackground="@color/purple_700"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
    tabmode="fixed"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
    app:tabIndicatorAnimationMode="elastic"
    app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_indicator"


    />

<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Que tienes en fragment_unete.xml ?

Comment: Actualice y añadi el xml de unete, el xml de los dos fragmentos solo es un texto y tienen FrameLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione cambiando la manera de poner el tabLayout usando el viewPager2

Inicio las variables

```
TabLayout tabLayout;
ViewPager2 pager2;
FragmentAdapter adapter;
```

En el onCreateView pongo

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_unete, container, false);


    tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    pager2 = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager2);

    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    adapter = new FragmentAdapter(fm, getLifecycle());
    pager2.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("First"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Second"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Third"));

    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            pager2.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });


    pager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            tabLayout.selectTab(tabLayout.getTabAt(position));
        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

Creo la clase FragmentAdapter

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(int position) {

    switch (position) {

        case 1:
            return new TwoUnete();

        case 2:
            return new ThreeUnete();

    }

    return new OneUnete();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 3;
}
```

Asi tengo el XML del fragmento `UneteFragmento`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/grey"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    tabmode="fixed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    app:tabBackground="@color/purple_700"
    app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_indicator"
    app:tabIndicatorAnimationMode="elastic"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"

    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white" />

<androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
    android:id="@+id/view_pager2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
    android:background="@color/purple_700" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

En realidad no estas usando un contenedor de los Fragmentos y tampoco estas realizando una transacciòn para agregarlos.

Revisa  [**Fragmentos**](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments?hl=es)

En el layout donde deseas realizar la transacciòn debes tener un `FrameLayout` el cual usarìas como contenedor, ejemplo:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
 
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/contenedor_fragments" 
        android:layout_weight="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Para agregar Fragments debes realizar una transacciòn (usando `FragmentTransaction`), definir la clase del `Fragment` y el contenedor donde se realizarà.

Ejemplo suponiendo que tu clase Fragmento se llama `MyFragment`:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    
transaction.replace(R.id.contenedor_fragments, new MyFragment());
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Es curioso porque si añado un 3 fragmento y tengo 3 tabs cuando vuelvo y no hay nada como en mi publicacion, si le doy al tab 3 aparece la informacion de los fragmentos menos la del fragmento 2. No llego a comprender bien su funcionamiento